# Firebase App Invite stop working with Dexguard

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, dexguard, firebase-invites

My app works fine. But in preparation to go to production, I applied Dexguard. With Dexguard Firebase AppInvite no longer works. When I send an invite, I get by the snackbar

> Message failed to send!

How do I make Firebase App Invite work with Dexguard? Btw, I have no problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I am using

```
 compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.0"
```

and

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `firebase` version `9.2.0` or later. Earlier versions do not include proper `keep` rules for internal classes that are getting accessed via reflection.